# How to change default Eclipse input language?

Tags: eclipse, layout, keyboard, non-english

I have Slovenian layout, it is English layout with extra characters (on <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) in fact. It's useful to have several languages in one layout.
Eclipse adds English layout  to my system by default. It is not convenient.
Is there a way to solve this problem? I really need my layout.
Eclipse Indigo SR2, Win7.